# です after some verbs (ほしいです)

Tags: grammar, copula

I've learned that です means something like the state of being, or close to the "be" verb.

Recently I found the following phrase: 犬がほしいです。
Why does it end with です if I am saying that "I want a dog"? (the verb is "want").

Comment: *Want* may be a verb in English, but 欲しい is an adjective in Japanese. Parts of speech are not always consistent between languages, especially unrelated languages.

Comment: You'll also find 好き (すき, like) is an adjective too. 犬がすきです。I like dogs.

Comment: です is not really a verb; it's more of a dummy verb that has no semantic content, but is used in sentences where a verb is obligatory in the syntax. Compare, for example, the use of the dummy pronoun _it_ in English sentences like 'It's raining' or 'It's been five years since I was last in Japan.' The word ほしい is simply an adjective, not a verb; です and its variants are added for the same reason that they would be in sentences like 犬が大きいです.

Comment: @Abbief no, actually 好き is a *noun* form (which can create na-adjectives). There is an actual verb 好く from which 好き derives, it just isn't ever used. In the plain form, 欲しいだ would not be grammatical, but 好きだ is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ほしい isn't a verb, it's an adjective. You can think of it like the English word "wanted"or "desired".  So, a ほしいもの is a wanted or desired thing.

Answer (score 39):

### Short answer:

It's a politeness marker.

---

### Long answer:

You can't think of Japanese in terms of English.

In the English sentence *I want a dog*, it's true that *want* is a verb.  But in the Japanese sentence 犬{いぬ}がほしいです, the word ほしい is an adjective, not a verb.  Even though you can express the same basic idea in both languages, the grammar to do so is quite different.

---

#### Why do we use *be* with adjectives in English?

In Standard English, we need a verb like *be* with nouns and adjectives, because nouns and adjectives can't form predicates on their own:

> 1a. *She silly.　　　　　 　 ←　ungrammatical
> 1b. She **is** silly.　　　　　　←　OK
>
> 2a. *She a programmer. 　 ←　ungrammatical
> 2b. She **is** a programmer.　←　OK

We need a verb like *be*.  Why?  It shows tense and subject–verb agreement, something nouns and adjectives can't do.  The basic meaning comes from the noun or adjective, but we need *be* there for grammatical reasons.

---

#### Adjectives can form predicates in Japanese

In Japanese, there's no need for a verb like *be* to show tense on adjectives.  Adjectives can indicate tense all on their own, using the endings -い and -かった:

> 3a. 美{うつく}し**い**　　　　　'is beautiful'
> 3b. 美{うつく}し**かった**　　　'was beautiful'

Each of these is a complete predicate on its own without です.  However, as you've noticed, people sometimes do add です:

> 4a. 美{うつく}しい**です**　　　'is beautiful (polite)'
> 4b. 美{うつく}しかった**です**　'was beautiful (polite)'

In this case, です doesn't have its usual grammatical function.  Instead, it's functioning as a politeness marker.  Note that tense is marked on the adjective with -い or -かった, so です doesn't change form to でした in 4b.

In other words, the *is* or *was* meaning is carried by the -い or -かった ending on the adjective.  The です part serves only to make the predicate polite.