# Why can't だ be used after an I-adjective?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, i-adjectives, copula, register

I have been constantly told that だ can not be placed after an I-adjective. Why is that?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35951/5010

Answer (score 25, accepted):

だ is the plain-form copula (the "is; to be" word).  In the plain form, い adjectives already form a complete predicate (the piece of a sentence or clause that can complete that sentence or clause).  In translation, it's like the い adjective already includes the "is" meaning -- so 速い would be "[it] *is* fast", not just "fast".

Since だ is only used to provide a way of finalizing plain-form clauses, it's redundant in cases where the plain-form clause is already a complete predicate -- such as when it ends in an い adjective.  Saying 速いだ might be like saying "[it] is is fast" in English -- the meaning is clear, but it's grammatically wrong and it sounds wrong.

Comment: @CraigHicks, です is a different case -- see the link posted above by naruto, http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35951/5010.  In summary, plain form だ only provides closure of a predicate, while polite form です also provides social register information (in this case, politeness) -- so い adjective + です is correct, and is in fact the required form for polite-register い adjectives.

Answer (score 20):

Grammatically speaking, there really are no adjectives in Japanese. i-adjectives are just special verbs. i-adjectives have many of the same inflections as do verbs, and they fulfill a grammatical role essentially equivalent to that of verbs. Therefore, 電車は速い is a complete sentence meaning "the train is fast", where 速い is the predicate.

i-adjective + です could be considered a special construction for the sake of politeness, similar to verb + ます. However, attaching an adjective to だ or でした, etc., would be ungrammatical or at least unidiomatic (because you would have two predicates). If you need the polite form of the past tense, instead of 早いでした, you would say 早かったです.

I know this is really confusing for many people. I used to be confused about the same question as well, but when I realized that i-adjectives are really a special category of verbs, it is easy to understand what is going on.

Comment: Wow! I have never consider i-adjective as a kind of verb before. Thanks

Comment: @AnhTuan, many of the conjugated forms of い adjectives are contractions with ある, where the contraction has so normalized that folks have forgotten about it.  Examples: 長かった = 長く + あった, 長かれ = 長く + あれ, etc.

Comment: This explanation is an excellently out of the box way of thinking about i adjectives. Thank you!