# Is 休みたいです more polite than 休みたい?

Tags: politeness

Is 休みたいです more polite than 休みたい？

It is necessary to say です in every "たい" word to sound more polite?

Comment: Related question (not a dupe): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43244/why-cant-だ-be-used-after-an-i-adjective

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is exactly the role of です here. です is a polite marker that you add to i-adjectives or i-adjectives like to make them polite. So yes, 休みたいです is more polite than 休みたい

Comment: Is it limited to adjectives? Is it for the same reason (politeness) that we add です after the たい form of verbs, such as in "誰かが答えたいか?" / "誰かが答えたいですか?"

Comment: @starckman Yes, that is exactly for the same reason.

Comment: 答えのためにありがとうございます