# How do you say this? (Warning NSFW)

Tags: grammar, transitivity, causation

How would you say: "I want a girl to sit on my face" in Japanese?

Would it be something like this: "俺の顔の上に女の子を座りたいだ"?

Answer (score 6):

Your sentence has two mistakes.

- In Japanese, i-adjectives (and i-adjective-like auxiliaries たい/ない) don't need a copula (だ). You should end this sentence with たい alone, without だ. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/35951/5010).
- 座りたい means "[I] want to sit" because 座る is always intransitive in Japanese. Using を doesn't automatically make it transitive. Instead of plain 座る, you have to use its [causative form](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-causative-form-saseru/), 座らせる.

The corrected version is:

> 俺の顔の上に女の子を座らせたい。

Comment: What about 俺の顔の上に女の子に座ってほしい。?

Comment: @andrewb The word order is unnatural. 女の子に俺の顔の上に座ってほしい would be fine.